# How to detect split window resized?

Tags: vim-windows, events

I'm aware that the `VimResized` event happens the main vim window is resized. Is there any event that happens when a split subwindow is resized? I'm looking for something like `WinResized`.

I'd like to define an `autocmd` that gets triggered when I move the boundary between split subwindows within the larger vim window.

Comment: It seems there is an open neovim feature request for a `WinResized` event: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/11532